# How to fix UIScrollView not scrolling in .xib issue?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, xib, xcode11.3

I have this project that requires to add `UIScrollView`. I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih7xyvyVyfU) since it is my first time to use `UIScrollView`. But unfortunately, it is not working successfully. My scrollView is inside a `.xib`.  Please help me fix this , aside from first time to use UIScrollView, I am not familiar with do's and don'ts in it. Also, been working from this for almost a week now. And to add some information, I removed the constraints in the objects inside ContentView, because even with or without constraints it is still not working.

**This is my current setup**

[image: My Current Setup]

**This is the setup from ScrollView to UIView**

[image: ScrollView > UIView]

**This is the setup from ContentView to ScrollView**

[image: ContentView>ScrollView]